# Java do while loop won't loop- Java (All int)

Tags: java, loops, int, do-while

Code for menu options won't loop, but has no errors. I intentionally wrote it similar to my while loop that loops just fine. I have to use only integers, and my instructor did tell me to turn my inputs into variables. Most of it isn't quite finished but I'm working on that at the same time as trying to figure all this out.

```
  //Loop to check user input
  num=-1;
  while (num<0)
  {
     //Getting user entered interger
     System.out.print("Please enter a positive number: ");
     num = kb.nextInt();

        //Ensuring positive interger
        if (num >= 0)
        {
           System.out.println("You've entered the number " + num + ".");
        }

        else
        {
           System.out.println("Error! The number you've entered is not a valid interger.");
         }   

   }
   copy = num;

  //Printing menu loop
  copy2 = -1;
  do
  {

     //Menu making
     System.out.println(" ");
     System.out.println("1. Enter a new number.");
     System.out.println("2. Print the number of odd digits, even digits, and zeros in the interger.");
     System.out.println("3. print if the number is light or heavy.");
     System.out.println("4. Print the prime numbers between 2 and the interger (inclusive).");
     System.out.println("5. Quit the program.");
     System.out.println(" ");
     System.out.print("Please enter your menu choice: ");
     choice = kb.nextInt();
     copy2 =choice;

        //Checking entry
        if (0<copy2 && copy2<=5)
        {
           System.out.println("You chose option " +copy2+".");
        }                

              //Option one
              if (copy2 == 1)
              {
                 System.out.print("Will work on soon.");
               }

              //Option two
              if (copy2 == 2)
              {
                 oddNum=0;
                 evenNum=0;
                 zero=0;
                 while (copy>0)
                 {
                    if (copy %10==0)
                    {
                       zero++;
                    }
                    else if (copy %2==1)
                    {
                      evenNum++;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                       oddNum++;
                      }
                   }
                   copy = copy/10;
                   System.out.println("Even numbers: " + evenNum+
                                               "\nOdd numbers: "+ oddNum + 
                                               "\nZeros: " +zero ); 
                }

                 //Option three
                 if (copy2 == 3)
                 {
                     loh = 0;
                     do
                     {  
                       System.out.println("To check if your number is light or heavy, we need a second interger.");
                       System.out.print("Please enter a second positive interger: ");
                       loh = kb.nextInt(); 

                          if (loh >= 0)
                          {
                             numWeight = ((loh +copy)/2);
                             //Test num weight
                             System.out.println("Check: " +numWeight);

                                   if (numWeight > copy)
                                   {
                                   System.out.print("The number " + copy + " compared to the number "
                                                             + loh + " is a heavy number.");
                                   }
                                   else
                                   {
                                   System.out.print("The number " + copy + " compared to the number "
                                                              + loh + " is a light number.");
                                   }
                              }
                             if (loh < 0)
                             {
                              System.out.println("Error! The number you've entered is not a valid interger.");
                              }     
                       }while (loh <=0);
                    }

                   //Option four
                  if (copy2 ==4)
                  { 
                   primeNumbers = 0;
                   for (int i=1; i<=copy; i++)
                   {
                      int counter = 0;
                      for(int prime = i; prime>=1; prime--)
                      {
                         if (i%prime==0)
                         {
                            counter = counter +1;
                          }
                       }
                       if (counter==2)
                       {
                         primeNumbers = primeNumbers + i;
                        }
                     }
                   System.out.println("Prime numbers from 2-"+copy+" are: ");
                   System.out.println(primeNumbers);
                   }

                   //Option five


        else
        {
        System.out.print("Error! Please enter a valid menu option.");
        }

     }while (copy2 <0 && copy2 >=6);    

   }//End main
}//End class
```

Comment: `while (copy2 <0 && copy2 >=6);` - This can never be true.  Try to find a number that is both less than zero and greater than or equal to 6 at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use switch case for your purpose. nested if/else isn't good idea for menu options but switch case make it more clear to understand what are you going to do.

```
 switch (num) {
      case c1:
            statements // they are executed if variable == c1
            System.out.println("1. Enter a new number.");
            break;
      case c2:
            System.out.println("2. Print the number of odd digits, even digits, and zeros in the interger."); 
            statements // they are executed if variable == c2
            break;
      case c3:
      case c4:        
            statements // they are executed if variable ==  any of the above c's
            break;
      . . .
      default:
            statements // they are executed if none of the above case is satisfied
            break;
    }
```